# SQLalchemy join get A not in B

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to make query to query A when B can't be joined in SQLalchemy. As illustrated below:

```
class A(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class B(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.id), nullable=False))
```

[image: upda]

First attempt:

```
A.query.join(B).filter(B.id==None).all()
```

The answer is:

```
A.query.outerjoin(B).filter(B.id==None).all()
```

Comment: what's your question/issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to outerjoin:

```
A.query.outerjoin(B).filter(B.id==None).all()
```